# Make the loop wait for the ajax call

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make this loop wait until the AJAX call has finished before moving onto the next iteration?

```
for(curr;curr < total;curr++) {
    $this.val('Uploading '+(curr+1)+' out of '+total);
    var tmpStr = JSON.stringify(o[curr]).replace("&", "and");
    tmp[0] = JSON.parse(tmpStr);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/post',
        data: "data="+JSON.stringify(tmp),
        success: function(msg) {

            var d = JSON.parse(msg);
            if (d.success) {

                //localStorage.removeItem("data");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
            $this.val('Upload to CMS');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, no. It's not **a** jax if it's synchronous, but I'd suggest you refactor your code rather than make it synchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) keyword with a recursive function. The `when` keyword allows you to wait for ajax calls. After an ajax call, when function sends the result to done function even it fails. You can expand your scenario by adding some error control into your ajax call. But I am giving this example:

```
function reCursive(curr,total)
{
    if(curr < total) 
    {
        $this.val('Uploading '+(curr+1)+' out of '+total);
        var tmpStr = JSON.stringify(o[curr]).replace("&", "and");
        tmp[0] = JSON.parse(tmpStr);

        $.when(function() 
        {
            return $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mvc.sivapi.sheffieldnetwork.com/form/submit/submit/meadowhallEaster/',
                data: "data="+JSON.stringify(tmp),
                success: function(msg) 
                {
                    var d = JSON.parse(msg);
                    if (d.success) 
                    {
                        //localStorage.removeItem("data");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
                    }
                },
                error: function(msg) 
                {
                    alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
                    $this.val('Upload to CMS');
                }
            });
        }).done(function (x) 
        {
            //When you get the result from your ajax call. Write your code here.
            curr++;
            reCursive(curr, total);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tidy up the formatting and you may get some points.

Comment: +1 Better, but use 4 spaces for a tab (like it is now)

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks, I couldn't find a shortcut for automatic 4 spaces in this editor. But thanks for fixing it.

Comment: This is roughly what I came up with myself, however this is much neater and cleaner than mine, thanks :).

Comment: @TomHart you are welcome. It is good that you liked it. :)

Answer (score 2):

While you can't make the loop `for` loop wait, you can rewrite the code to use another style of invocation  to run.

```
function runOnce(curr) {
  $this.val('Uploading ' + (curr + 1) + ' out of ' + total);
  var tmpStr = JSON.stringify(o[curr]).replace("&", "and");
  tmp[0] = JSON.parse(tmpStr);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mvc.sivapi.sheffieldnetwork.com/form/submit/submit/meadowhallEaster/',
    data: "data=" + JSON.stringify(tmp),

    // ***ADDED HERE*
    always: {
      if (curr < total) {
        runOnce(curr+1);
      } else {
        alert("All done-- you could call your next function from here.");
      }
    },
    success: function (msg) {

      var d = JSON.parse(msg);
      if (d.success) {
        //localStorage.removeItem("data");
      } else {
        alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
      }
    },
    error: function (msg) {
      alert("Data failed to upload, please try again");
      $this.val('Upload to CMS');
    }
  });
}

// Set things up and run it once.
// The '0' is what the loop index would be.
runOnce(0);
```

Comment: Recursion for the win

Comment: @JonP - Technically, this is *not* recursion because there is only one instance of `runOnce` on the stack...

Comment: Getting side tracked, but doesn't the fact the function calls itself as part of the `always` condition make it recursion... or is there some subtlety I'm missing out on?

Comment: @JonP - Yes, there is a subtle difference. In recursion the original function hangs around so you can `return` a value to it and you have as many instances of the function on the stack as you do invocations. In this case, the function is simply being re-invoked by an event (`always` in this case.)  There is only *one* copy of `runOnce` on the stack at a time.